# Touchscreen equivalent for Mousedrag for a painting grid in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch

I'm trying to build a paint like program (Etch-a-Sketch of The Odin Project) where when I drag the mouse across the paint grid, it colours them black.

[image]

I am basing my function hold() from [how to implement mousemove while mouseDown pressed js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817534/how-to-implement-mousemove-while-mousedown-pressed-js). and the code works for a mouse on a pc.

The code:

```
   //FUNCTION TO DRAG AND PAINT 
   function hold(){
        var items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");
              
    
       items.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event){
                 if(event.buttons == 1){
                     event.preventDefault();      

                     item.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                 }
                
           });
       });
    
    }
```

However, when I try the same for mobile/touch devices, using the code as mentioned in the same page for touch enabled devices, it does not work. The user has to tap everytime to colour the grids black instead of tap and drag like it was in the case of using the mousepointer for click and drag.

The code:

```
    //FUNCTION TO DRAG AND PAINT 
    function hold(){
        var items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");
              
    
       items.forEach(item => {
               item.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event){
                     if(event.touches.length == 1){
                         event.preventDefault();    
                     item.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                 }
               
           });
       });
```

Can someone please help me with this? I will be grateful if someone can point out what would be the equivalent of mousedrag for a touch device?

Thank you!

I tried changing the code as mentioned above but it did not work.